# How can I use both $http and $timeout in AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive, timeout

This is a part of my codes

```
Object_Angular.directive("ntgChangeScanInnerHtmlWorkshop", ["$timeout", function($timeout){ ...
```

But I need to also get access to `$http` since I want to load things from my API. How can I do this?

What I have is a display of `_id`s in a `<p></p>`. Let say I have `<p>{{collections._id}}</p>`. I want that `<p></p>` to display the name field (`collections.String_Name`) not the `_id`. So I think to take the inner HTML of the `<p>{{collections._id}}</p>` after the value loads and then GET the `String_Name` from the API via `{ _id: innerHTMLValueOfP }` then in `.success` I do set back the inner value with `result.String_Name`. Hence I need to have `$http` and `$timeout` in my directive to achieve this.

Comment: share proper code, so it will help to understand the question.

Comment: You seem to know how to inject a service so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Not sure if you were just looking for this, but can't you just type `["$timeout", "$http", function($timeout, $http){ ...`? Your question is kinda hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using $http in directive

```
app.directive('myTag', ['$http', function($http) {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,     
      scope:{
      src:"="       
    },
   controller:function($scope){
    console.info("enter directive controller");
    $scope.gallery = [];

   console.log($scope.src);

    $http({method: 'GET', url:$scope.src}).then(function (result) {
                       console.log(result);                              
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });
        } 
    }
 }]);
 or
 app.directive('example', function( $http){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      link: function($scope,$element,$timeout){

            $http.post('/example', {
                data
            }).success(function(data){
            }).error(function(data){});
        }
   });
```